# Call specified method from base class

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

Not sure how to explain it well, so I will just provide a sample of code that shows my problem:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base() = default;
  ~Base() = default;

  virtual void stuff(std::shared_ptr<Base> b) = 0;
};

class DerivedA : public Base {
public:
  DerivedA() = default;
  ~DerivedA() = default;

  void stuff(std::shared_ptr<Base> b) {
    std::cout << "stuff Base"
              << "\n";
  }
};

class DerivedB : public Base {
public:
  DerivedB() = default;
  ~DerivedB() = default;

  void stuff(std::shared_ptr<Base> b) {
    std::cout << "stuff Base"
              << "\n";
  }
  void stuff(std::shared_ptr<DerivedA> b) {
    std::cout << "stuff Derived"
              << "\n";
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::shared_ptr<Base> b1(new DerivedA());
  std::shared_ptr<Base> b2(new DerivedB());

  b1->stuff(b2);
  b2->stuff(b1);
  return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
stuff Base
stuff Base
```

Now, I suppose it is not possible to call the derived method as it doesn't exist in the base class.

My question is: Is there a way to call `stuff(std::shared_ptr<DerivedA> b)` using the base class ?

[EDIT]

I already thought about the visitor pattern (should have said it and be more specific).

My classes represent Entities and I have to check collisions between them. However a collision between A & B will have a different effect than between B & C.

I agree that it will work, but it means that I will have to define tons of methods.

Is there a more elegant way to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a job for the Visitor pattern !
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: Looks like you are getting mixed up between method (or any function) overloading, and (virtual) method overriding.

Comment: I edited my question to answer @Louen

Comment: You must come up with a generic collision algorithm that uses only virtuals via base pointer. Something like `Collision check_collision(std::shared_ptr<Base> first, std::shared_ptr<Base> second);`

Comment: It's what I have, but how should i code the different behaviors, for ex a ball bounce on a wall but kills a player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is commonly called multiple dispatch, or a multimethod. There is no direct language support for this in C++, but you can explicitly implement it yourself. Basically, you have one virtual function which dispatches to another virtual function with a concrete object:

```
struct DerivedA;
struct DerivedB;

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void stuff(shared_ptr<Base> ) = 0;

    virtual void dispatch_stuff(Base& ) = 0;
    virtual void dispatch_stuff(DerivedA& p) { return dispatch_stuff(static_cast<Base&>(p)); }
    virtual void dispatch_stuff(DerivedB& p) { return dispatch_stuff(static_cast<Base&>(p)); }

struct DerivedA : Base {
    void stuff(shared_ptr<Base> rhs) override {
        rhs->dispatch_stuff(*this);
    }

    void dispatch_stuff(Base& ) { /* default */ }
    void dispatch_stuff(DerivedA& ) { /* specific A-A stuff */ }
};
```

This way:

```
b1->stuff(b2); // calls b2->dispatch_stuff(DerivedA& )
b2->stuff(b1); // calls b1->dispatch_stuff(DerivedB& )
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: Is there a way to call 
>   `stuff(std::shared_ptr<DerivedA> b)` using the base class ?

No, because the `Base` class interface doesn't implement the method you want to call. Even though the `Base` class pointer is referring to a `DerivedB` object, and through poilformism you can resolve the method with the respect to the type of the object pointed by the pointer (i.e. DerivedB), you can only call the method defined in the `Base` class. Therefore, you cannot call `stuff(std::shared_ptr<DerivedA> b)` using a `Base` pointer that points to a `DerivedB` object.

For example:

```
 std::shared_ptr<Base> b1(new DerivedA());
  std::shared_ptr<Base> b2(new DerivedB());
  std::shared_ptr<DerivedA> a1(new DerivedA());
  std::shared_ptr<DerivedB> bb1(new DerivedB());

  b1->stuff(b2);
  b2->stuff(b1);
  b2->stuff(a1); // b2 is the only class that implement stuff(std::shared_ptr<DerivedA> b)
  bb1->stuff(a1)
```

output:

```
stuff Base
stuff Base
stuff Base
stuff Derived
stuff Base
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are trying to solve is called the [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) problem, which means you're trying to invoke a behaviour depending on the concrete type of two objects. Looking up this term on google or here may yield you some interesting results.

First thing, one way or another, you're going to have to write a lot of functions since if you have N different types there are N*N possible pairings. (N*N/2 if order doesn't matter, which is probably the case in your collision scenario).

The [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is one of the canonical solutions to the double dispatch problem.

There are others, depending on what matters to you. Off the top of my head, for example, if the number of subtypes is limited and known at compile time, you can for example have an index for each type and a 2D array of function pointers to call (not very elegant nor very object oriented but quite efficient in terms of performance).

If you fear that the number of functions is likely to cause code duplication you can always factor the code inside a function, or a class ( something like `CollisionPairBehavior` ).